# SQL Delete com join, union no Firebird

Tags: firebird

Como seria um Exemplo de SQL Delete com Join ou Union?  Eu vi por aqui no stackoverflow como fazer no MySQL no sql Server mais no firebird não achei e nem achei em outros fóruns. o meu SQL ficou assim

```
DELETE FROM ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS
WHERE CODIGO_ANDAMENTO in(
  SELECT
    T2.CODIGO_ANDAMENTO
  FROM ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T2
    LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T3 ON T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO
  WHERE
    (T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO)  AND (T3.FASE_PROCESSO LIKE 'ARQUIVADO')    
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    T2.CODIGO_ANDAMENTO
  FROM ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS T2
    LEFT JOIN PROCESSOS T3 ON T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO
  WHERE
    (T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO_AUX = T3.NUMERO_PROCESSO2)  AND (T3.FASE_PROCESSO2 LIKE 'ARQUIVADO'))
```

Comment: Será que, está faltando alguma coisa no sql? Tipo passar a tabela no Delete tipo DELETE ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS FROM ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que usar o `EXISTS`.

Verifique no manual oficial:
[Firebird DELETE](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-delete.html)

```
DELETE FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM employee_project ep
  WHERE e.emp_no = ep.emp_no);
```